# Undefined reference when creating entry point in shared library clang

Tags: c++, clang, dllexport, entry-point

I have an issue I don't understand. My project is quite simple for now. I have a shared library Engine which is called by my executable. I'm trying to move the entry point inside my shared library, so the executable part only has functions and some class to create.

---EDIT: I edit to post the project as it is reproductible easily.

To do so, I have these files in my shared library:

1. entry.h
2. BaseGame.h
3. Application.cpp

Here is entry.h

```
#include "BaseGame.h"

extern game* create_game();

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    auto testgame = create_game();
    delete testgame;
    return 0;
}
```

BaseGame.h

```
class __declspec(dllexport) game
{
public:
    game() = default;
    virtual ~game();
    virtual bool initialize() =0;
    virtual bool update(float deltaTime) =0;
    virtual bool render(float deltaTime) =0;
    virtual void on_resize() =0;
};
```

Application.cpp

```
#include "BaseGame.h"
class __declspec(dllexport) Application
{
public:
    Application()=default;
    ~Application()=default;
};
```

And in my executable, I have two files entry.cpp which defines create_game and my_game.h which inherited from game.

entry.cpp

```
#include <entry.h>
#include "my_game.h"

game* create_game()
{
    return new myGame;
}
```

and my_game.h:

```
class myGame : public game
{
public:
    myGame(){};
    ~myGame() override = default;
    bool initialize() override;
    bool update(float deltaTime) override;
    bool render(float deltaTime) override;
    void on_resize() override;
};
```

my_game.cpp:

```
#include "my_game.h"

bool myGame::initialize()
{
    return true;
}
bool myGame::update(float deltaTime)
{
    return true;
}
bool myGame::render(float deltaTime)
{
    return true;
}
void myGame::on_resize()
{
}
```

What I don't understand is that I always get an linker error when building my exe:

```
Création de la bibliothèque ..\bin\testbed.lib et de l'objet ..\bin\testbed.exp
entry-3b33f2.o : error LNK2019: symbole externe non résolu "public: virtual __cdecl game::~game(void)" (??1game@@UEAA@XZ) référencé dans la fonction "public: virtual __cdecl myGame::~myGame(void)" (??1myGame@@UEAA@XZ)
..\bin\testbed.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 externes non résolus
```

Also here is how i build my shared library:

```
SET assembly=Engine
SET compilerFlags=-g -shared -Wvarargs -Wall -Werror
SET includeFlags=-Isrc
SET linkerFlags=-luser32
SET defines=-D_DEBUG_EG -DGEXPORT -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

ECHO "Building %assembly%%..."
clang++ %cFilenames% %compilerFlags% -o ../bin/%assembly%.dll %defines% %includeFlags% %linkerFlags%
```

And here is my executable:

```
SET assembly=testbed
SET compilerFlags=-g 
REM -Wall -Werror
SET includeFlags=-Isrc -I../Engine/src/
SET linkerFlags=-L../bin/ -lEngine.lib
SET defines=-D_DEBUG_EG -DGIMPORT
clang++ %cFilenames% %compilerFlags% -o ../bin/%assembly%.exe %defines% %includeFlags% %linkerFlags%
```

Even if game is exported. Does anyone see something wrong? PS: I'm using Clang as the compiler.

Comment: Unrelated: Never define `main` in a header file. Also, this will not compile so we won't be able to reproduce the linking error. Please provide a [mre].

Comment: I've tried to implement the member function, it's always the constructor and destructor (i think because it's the only one i'm using right now) that are a problem.
And i don't understand why i couldn't define main in a header file. I'm creating this project inspiring myself with some other project. And i've seen it every time:
In C like
https://github.com/travisvroman/kohi/commit/24e2a8a09314969464931cbdb2840b4677f8dee3#diff-f5c14ecdafa88313be75815db762bc7ef7de814eeec488924917e75d618e7925
In c++:
https://github.com/TheCherno/Hazel/blob/master/Hazel/src/Hazel/Core/EntryPoint.h

Comment: You do understand that every translation unit you compile that includes (either directly or indirectly) the header file with the `main` definition in it will get this definition? There's absolutely no reason for this complication. Why [Travis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4463265/travis-vroman) removed `main.c` and moved the `main` definition to a header file is a mystery to me.

Comment: I get that the main function (as entry point) is mandatory include everywhere, it's the first function called. I though that this way of doing has for goal to put the main function in the shared library and be able to call it ( by including the corresponding file, here entry.h) in the executable. Like that the main definition is in our shared library and not in our executable.

Comment: Having `main` in a shared library (even if properly defined in a `.c`/`.cpp` file instead of a header file) sounds like yet another bad idea. Oh well, you do what you want ...

Comment: I just edit my question with a minimal reproductible example. I have the same error with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `game` class lacks a destructor definition. I suggest making it `default`:

```cpp
class myGame : public game
{
public:
    myGame(){};
    ~myGame() override = default;          // here
    bool initialize() override;
    bool update(float deltaTime) override;
    bool render(float deltaTime) override;
    void on_resize() override;
};
```

You may also remove the default constructor and destructor from `myGame`. It'll be default constructible and have a `virtual` destructor by default.

```cpp
class myGame : public game
{
public:
    // myGame(){};                   // remove
    // ~myGame() override = default; // remove
    // ...
```

Other notes:

- All your header files should have header guards to prevent including the same file twice in one translation unit.
- `my_game.h` should `#include "BaseGame.h"` to get the definition of `game`.

Comment: Oh sry, i didn't see this simple mistake. I didn't realize it's just that . Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You example is not entirely complete. I assume the destructor `~game()` is actually defined in some cpp file of the shared library. And `my_game.h` needs to include `BaseGame.h` (since `myGame` derives from `game`). So basically `my_game.cpp` in the executable ends up seeing the definition of `game` as shown, including the `__declspec(dllexport)`. However, the executable should not see `__declspec(dllexport)` (i.e. the exe should not export `game`) but rather it should see `__declspec(dllimport)` (i.e. the exe should **import** `game`). So you want to define `game` with `__declspec(dllexport)` while building the dll and `__declspec(dllimport)` while building the executable.

The [typical way](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/importing-into-an-application-using-declspec-dllimport) to conditionally have one or the other is by using a macro and changing its definition based on a preprocessor symbol which is different for the exe and the dll. For example (adapted from the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/importing-into-an-application-using-declspec-dllimport)):

```
// Either in BaseGame.h or in a dedicated header
// that gets included by BaseGame.h.
#ifdef EXPORT_GAME_SYMBOLS
   #define GAME_DECLSPEC  __declspec(dllexport)
#else
   #define GAME_DECLSPEC  __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

// BaseGame.h
class GAME_DECLSPEC game
{ ... class definition ... };
```

While building the dll, you do define `EXPORT_GAME_SYMBOLS` in the preprocessor (`-DEXPORT_GAME_SYMBOLS`). But while building the executable, you do **not** define `EXPORT_GAME_SYMBOLS`.

The linker complains only about the destructor of `game` because only the destructor has a non-inline implementation in your example. The default constructor is inline (`game() = default;`, meaning that an export is not necessary for the linker to find an implementation) and the other functions are pure (meaning that they do not have an implementation to begin with).
Hence, an alternative here would be to completely remove the export/import stuff from `game` and define the destructor inline, too (`virtual ~game() = default;`).
But of course, if everything is inline, you do not need to build a shared library to begin with...

Side notes:

- The `__declspec(dllexport)` on `Application` makes no sense since it is in a `.cpp` file of the dll, meaning that code in the executable can never see the definition of `Application`. (Except if you `#include "Application.cpp"`, which you shouldn't.) So no need to export the symbol.
- As others have noted, having the `main()` in the header file is uncommon. You could move it e.g. to `my_game.cpp` or a dedicated `main.cpp` in your exe project.

Comment: Well, i understand that having main in header file isn't common. But as far i've seen it's the only way to have main function inside shared library (not recommended either, i know) But it's quite common in many engine. And i don't know how to move the entry point in shared library without that. If you know a safer way? Or a better way?

Comment: @miyoku You can put the `main` function in a `.cpp` file and still create a library with it. That would be better although, I wouldn't actually put `main` in the library at all.